# Clojure: How to pass parameters when reducing over functions

Tags: clojure

From http://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/, the following code will trim whitespace and replace "lol" with "LOL".

```
(require '[clojure.string :as s])
(defn clean
  [text]
  (s/replace (s/trim text) #"lol" "LOL"))

(clean "My boa constrictor is so sassy lol!  ")
; => "My boa constrictor is so sassy LOL!"
```

Now, according to the website the code below which reduce over functions is equivalent to what we have above.

```
(defn clean
      [text]
      (reduce (fn [string string-fn] (string-fn string))
              [s/trim #(s/replace % #"lol" "LOL")]))
```

**Question:** I don't understand how the `text` parameter get passed into the anonymous function within reduce function. How can I write a similar code that explicitly pass the parameter `text` into the anonymous function within the reduce function ?

Comment: This seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @ntalbs it would work if `text` were an arg before the vector of funtions.

Comment: I gave some more descriptions to the question. Please do not downvote. @noisesmith I tried adding `text` before the vector of functions already. It didn't work

Comment: Okay. I made a dumb mistake. I forgot to implement `(require '[clojure.string :as s])` first. That's why it didn't work. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0):

The `reduce` function takes an optional argument, the initial value of the reduction. If it is not provided, the first item of the last arg is used instead (which of course would not work at all in this case, but does work when you have a sequence of inputs that are of the same effective type as the initial value).

```
user> (defn clean
        [text]
        (reduce (fn [string string-fn] (string-fn string))
                text
                [clojure.string/trim #(clojure.string/replace % #"lol" "LOL")]))
#'user/clean
user> (clean "My boa constrictor is so sassy lol!  ")
"My boa constrictor is so sassy LOL!"
```